# Why does \WithSuffix\providecommand overwrite command already defined by instance of thmtools's restatable environment?

Tags: macros, include, thmtools, starred-version

Consider the output

[image: Output of MWE]

of this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{suffix}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{restatable}[Made-Up Theorem]{theorem}{MadeUpTheorem}
    This is a made-up theorem.
\end{restatable}

Now, let's repeat the restatable theorem:
\MadeUpTheorem*

Next, let's try to define a new command if it has not yet been defined.
\WithSuffix\providecommand\MadeUpTheorem*{ABC}

Let's see what happens:
\MadeUpTheorem*

\textbf{Why does this output ABC? Why not the original theorem?}

I thought providecommand only defined a command if it had not already been defined.

\end{document}
```

- ***(Optional) Q:*** Why does this output ABC? Why does it not again output the original made-up theorem?
- ***Q:*** More importantly, how can I "redefine" `\MadeUpTheorem*` only if it has not been defined previously?

It seems that `\providecommand` overwrites the original definition of `\MadeUpTheorem*` even if it's already defined.

In my use-case, the original `restatable` will be in a different file than the calling of `\MadeUpTheorem*`. It is compiled using `\include`, but during intermediate compilations it is *not* included, hence not defined. But during the final compilation, it is included, and so "ABC" should not be printed.

Comment: Try `\ProvideDocumentCommand\MadeUpTheorem{s}{abc}`.

Comment: What would be the reason for doing such a thing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, thank you. That worked great!

Comment: @egreg I tried to explain it shortly, perhaps confusingly, in the final paragraph of OP. The main takeaway is that I cannot compile different ``\include``-s independently without this fix. An instance of restatable may be referenced/accessed under a different file from where it was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **(Optional) Q**: Why does this output ABC? Why does it not again output the original made-up theorem?

Because actually the if-defined-then-skip conditional executed by `\providecommand` acts on an inner command `\WSF:\MadeUpTheorem the character *` (composed by `\csname\SuffixName\MadeUpTheorem*\endcsname`), not `\MadeUpTheorem` itself.

Since that inner commands is always undefined, the behavior of `\MadeUpTheorem` followed by a star is always changed. That means, the net effects of `\WithSuffix\providecommand...` and `\WithSuffix\newcommand...` are the same.

See an example without `thmtools` but using a manually defined `\mycmd*`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{fvextra} % for \EscVerb

\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{\@ifstar{\mycmd@{starred, original}}{\mycmd@{not starred}}}
\def\mycmd@#1{#1\par}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\subsection*{initially}
\mycmd
\mycmd*

\subsection*{after \EscVerb{\\WithSuffix\\providecommand\\mycmd*{...}}}
\WithSuffix\providecommand\mycmd*{starred, after \EscVerb{\\WithSuffix}}
\mycmd
\mycmd*
\end{document}
```

[image]

> **Q**: More importantly, how can I "redefine" `\MadeUpTheorem*` only if it has not been defined previously?

In general, there's no easy solution. The key is that `\MadeUpTheorem*` is not a single command, but `\MadeUpTheorem` followed by a star with `\MadeUpTheorem` defined to behave differently depending on if it's followed by an optional star.

A general conditional checks "if a command/macro accepts an optional star" is non-trivial, but if you know the command is defined by some utility command hence/or its replacement text follows some pattern, it's possible to check against such patterns and provide a partial solution.

For example, the `\MadeUpTheorem` defined by `\begin{restatable}[Made-Up Theorem]{theorem}{MadeUpTheorem}` has the pattern

```tex
% see https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/blob/0.74/source/thm-restate.dtx#L201-L207
\gdef\MadeUpTheorem{%
  \@ifstar{%
    \thmt@thisistheonefalse\csname thmt@stored@MadeUpTheorem\endcsname
  }{%
    \thmt@thisistheonetrue\csname thmt@stored@MadeUpTheorem\endcsname
  }%
}
```

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{fvextra} % for \EscVerb

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{\@ifstar{\mycmd@{starred, original}}{\mycmd@{not starred}}}
\def\mycmd@#1{#1\par}

\newcommand\starred@restatable[1]{%
  \unexpanded{%
    \@ifstar{%
      \thmt@thisistheonefalse\csname thmt@stored@#1\endcsname
    }{%
      \thmt@thisistheonetrue\csname thmt@stored@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand\IfRestatableTF[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\starred@temp{\ExpandArgs{e}\starred@restatable{\scantokens\expandafter{\expanded{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}\noexpand}}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx#1\starred@temp
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{restatable}[Made-Up Theorem]{theorem}{MadeUpTheorem}
    This is a made-up theorem.
\end{restatable}

\subsection*{initially}
\mycmd
\mycmd*

\MadeUpTheorem
\MadeUpTheorem*

\subsection*{after \EscVerb{\\WithSuffix\\providecommand\\mycmd*{...}}}
\WithSuffix\providecommand\mycmd*{starred, after \EscVerb{\\WithSuffix}}
\mycmd
\mycmd*

\IfRestatableTF\MadeUpTheorem
  {}
  {\WithSuffix\newcommand\MadeUpTheorem*{ABC}}
\MadeUpTheorem
\MadeUpTheorem*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note @Ulrike Fischer's suggestion (`\ProvideDocumentCommand\MadeUpTheorem{s}{abc}`) checks if `\MadeUpTheorem` itself is defined, not if `\MadeUpTheorem` is defined *and* accepts an optional star.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case, Ulrike Fischer's solution seems to work. But I will definitely keep your reply in mind if something breaks in the future.